# Cannot see details of the close reason in Reopen queue

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

In Reopen queue, the details of the close reason for **Not suitable for this site** are not shown.

I only see this text:

[image]

Therefore, I always need to open the question in a new window to see the close reason:

[image]

A reviewer needs this information in the second image o be sure if "Original close reason(s) were resolved".

[image]

Comment: This might be worth asking on Meta SE (there may already be a Q&A there on it, so remember to search first)